# Swift, filter, array

Tags: массивы, swift, button, filter

Такой вопрос:
Есть 21 объект

```
@IBOutlet var coins: [UIButton]!
```

я создал еще один массив, но пустой:

```
var coins2 = []
```

Забираем от 1 до трех coins. Сначала я, потом Ai.

код для меня:

```
 @IBAction func coinsHidden(button: UIButton) {
     button.hidden = true
     coins2 = coins.filter{ $0.hidden}
}
```

код для Ai:

```
 @IBAction func endTurn(sender: UIButton!) {   
     let numberToDelete = Int(arc4random_uniform(3)) + 1
     for _ in 0..<numberToDelete {
         let tag = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(coins.count)))
        coins[tag].hidden = true
        coins2 = coins.filter{ $0.hidden }
   }
}
```

Проблема в том что, Ai берет те coins, которые уже hidden = true. Как сделать, чтоб он взял только те, которые еще не брали?

Comment: я на  ваш прошлый вопрос по моему уже писал - отфильтруйте coins чтобы остались только видимые и пусть ваш AI выбирает только из них

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот так примерно это должно выглядеть

```
    let numberToDelete = Int(arc4random_uniform(3)) + 1
    for _ in 0..<numberToDelete {
        let coins2:Array = coins.filter({ $0.hidden == false })   //создать временный массив с видимыми элементами
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(coins2.count))) //выбрать что убрать
        let buttonToHide = coins2[index]                          //взять из отфильтрованного массива соответствующий объект
        let indexOfButton = coins.indexOf(buttonToHide)           //найти его же в оригинальном массиве
        (coins2[indexOfButton!] as UIButton).hidden = true        //спрятать в оригинальном массиве

    }
```

Comment: странно, у меня все работало